# C# VLC activex component focus element when playing

Tags: c#, vlc

I want to make mousescroll volume up and down event when the player is playing, but when the player starting the videofile, the focus is gone. How can i "force focus" to the volume trackbar?

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is install a [MessageFilter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.imessagefilter(v=vs.110).aspx) on your form. This will get you any mouse input before VLC's control.

Have your form implement IMessageFilter and the PreMessageFilter method which will get you your mousewheel. The paramater is a Win32 message. Here's some info on the [WM_MOUSEWHEEL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645617(v=vs.85).aspx) event.

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form, IMessageFilter

    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
    {
        const int WM_MOUSEWHEEL = 0x020A;
        if (m.Msg == WM_MOUSEWHEEL)
        {
            // The wheeldelta is stored in the highorder of WParam.
            // The value of which will be 120 (positive for forward, negative for backward).
            int hiWord = m.WParam.ToInt32() >> 16;

            // So use the delta as a way to increment/decrement the volume
            this.axVLCPlugin21.volume += 10 * (hiWord / 120);
            Trace.WriteLine("vol: " + this.axVLCPlugin21.volume);
         }

        return false;
    }
```

And also don't forget to register the message filter with the Application. You can do this in your form's constructor.

```
    public Form1()
    {
        Application.AddMessageFilter(this);

        InitializeComponent();
    }
```